# How to save username & password for App in iOS?

Tags: ios, keychainitemwrapper

1. I have an Username & password. I want to save it for an App. If app will deleted then username password will save for that app only, during reinstall the app it will work. If I instal the app in another devices then that user name password will be work.
2. For same thing  I have some data. I want to save that for future. Means suppose I deleted the App and again reinstall the app again or instal the app in difference device then that data will be secure.

For this purpose I used iCloud, but its taking too much time for sync & sometimes its not working properly.

Please anybody can suggest me how can I doable with this above 2 problems ?

Note: I don't want to use web services. My app is without webservices.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: then use parse for backend side

Comment: You can use the keychain with iCloud support; this will meet your single device needs.  For it to work across devices then the user must have turned on iCloud keychain

Comment: To share your credentials across different devices, you need some sort of web service (iCloud _is_ an instance of a web service, in a sense); If its syncing is too slow for you, then you're out of luck...

Comment: What are these credentials being used to protect?

Answer (score 0):

**iCloud**

[Store Private credential using iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html)

**WebService**

1. At first time, User install App, make one service to check using DeviceToken user Device is registered or Not.
2. if user device is registered then gives you username and password, otherwise Skip and display login page.
3. At login page you have to pass deviceToken, username and password thorough webservice.
4. Now you remove and again install app, Apps check using web service to passing DeviceToken, if user is login previous then give UserName and Password.

Comment: Clearly I mention, I don't want to use web service. Please suggest me without service call

Comment: using iCloud we can save our username password & some data also. ?

Comment: yes you can save publicCloudDatabase or PrivateCloudDatabase,

Comment: Ok , I am going through ur code, if i face any issue then i'll disturb u :)